# Apóstrofo causando erro ao inserir dados no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Sou iniciante no PHP e estou criando um projeto pessoal para consolidar meus conhecimentos até que me deparei com um problema, ao inserir um nome que possua um apóstrofe este apóstrofe faz com que o `INSERT INTO` não seja executado fazendo com que os dados não sejam gravados no banco de dados MySQL.

A consulta e o resto está todo correto pois testei retirar o apóstrofe e os dados foram gravados corretamente e foram exibidos no site corretamente, eu gostaria de saber como faço para tratar esses eventuais erros de caracteres na hora da inserção.

Código PHP

```
<?php require_once "topo-painel.php"; ?>

<?php

$array_erro = array(
    UPLOAD_ERR_OK           => "Sem erro.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE     => "O arquivo enviado excede o limite definido no PHP.ini .",
    UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE    => "O arquivo enviado excede o limite definido no formulário.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL      => "O upload do arquivo não terminou ou foi cancelado antes de ser concluido.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE      => "Nenhum arquivo foi enviado.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR   => "Não foi definida uma pasta temporaria.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE   => "Falha ao escrever arquivo em disco",
    UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION    => "Uma extensão do PHP interrompeu o upload do arquivo."
);

if ( isset($_POST["cadastrar"]) ) {

    $champ_nome     = $_POST["nome-champ"];
    $champ_desc     = $_POST["desc-champ"];
    $champ_avatar   = $_FILES["avatar-champ"]["name"];

    $adiciona_champ = "INSERT INTO campeoes (champ_nome, champ_descricao, champ_avatar) VALUES ('$champ_nome', '$champ_desc', 'img/campeoes/{$champ_avatar}' )";

    $executa_champ = mysqli_query($conexao, $adiciona_champ);

    $arquivo_temporario = $_FILES["avatar-champ"]["tmp_name"];
    $arquivo = basename( $_FILES["avatar-champ"]["name"] );

    $diretorio = "../img/campeoes";

    if ( move_uploaded_file($arquivo_temporario, $diretorio."/".$arquivo) ) {
        $mensagem = "Arquivo publicado";
    }else {
        $numero_erro = $_FILES["avatar-champ"]["error"];
        $mensagem = $array_erro[$numero_erro];
    }
}

?>

<?php

?>

<?php //require_once "menu-painel.php"; ?>



<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3 mtl">
            <form action="adiciona-campeao.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nome-champ">Nome do campeão</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome-champ" name="nome-champ" placeholder="Informe o nome do campeão">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="desc-champ">Descrição do campeão</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc-champ" name="desc-champ" placeholder="Informe a descrição do campeão">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="avatar-champ">Avatar do campeão</label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3145728" />
                    <input type="file" name="avatar-champ" value="avatar" id="avatar-champ">
                    <p class="help-block">Tamanho máximo de 3MB</p>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="CADASTRAR" name="cadastrar" class="btn btn-outlined btn-white" />
            </form>

            <?php 
if ( isset($mensagem) ) {
    echo $mensagem;
}
            ?>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<?php require_once "rodape-painel.php"; ?>
```

Comment: Você poderia testar com `$champ_nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome-champ', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);` e retornar o resultado obtido? Assim o parâmetro pego do post com está função será tratado. Você tem várias formas alem do `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS.` Documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php

Comment: Rafael Withoeft Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente o nome foi gravado no banco da seguinte forma Cho&#39;Gath e exibido com o apóstrofe no site Muito obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: Por nada! :), quando for capturar parâmetros seja por $_POST ou $_GET, **sempre** que possível, utilize o filter_input.

Comment: @Qmechanic73 Feito... obrigado :)

Comment: vc pode utilizar tbm o mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: [Pode não, DEVE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53610/#comment109936_53610). o filter input não é a solução correta para este caso, e sim o _escape_.

Comment: @FelipeDumont recomendo também além da implementação do filter, o uso de Prepared Statement. Vide: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php ou http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php ou http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629328/how-to-use-mysqli-prepared-statements-in-php

Comment: converter para htmlentities para esse caso e casos gerais , é um erro. O certo é escapar os caracteres especiais e reservados do sql.

Comment: @FelipeDumont Forneci uma nova solução mais legal para você na resposta. Observe a parte do edit. Como houve muitos questionamentos sobre o filter_input (com razão), resolvei editar a resposta e fornecer uma solução mais correta. Agradeço a observação do Bacco e Daniel;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### EDIT

A solução mais vista como a ideal, seria o uso do `Prepared Statement, que chamarei de "PS"`; Vamos ao exemplo:

Mantemos sua string original fornecida pelo usuário e então usamos o `PS` que cuidará do resto (observe que não haverá o "sanitize" da sua string, então seus apóstrofos aparecerão corretamente no banco de dados, mas sem nenhum risco pois ele `(PS)`, cuidará da segurança).

```
$champ_nome     = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome-champ'); //Mantêm a string original
$champ_desc     = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'desc-champ'); //Mantêm a string original
$champ_avatar   = 'img/campeoes/' . $_FILES["avatar-champ"]["name"];

//Fornecemos ? nos lugares dos valores, que indicarão um "parâmetro";
$adiciona_champ = $sua_conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO campeoes (champ_nome, champ_descricao, champ_avatar) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

//Bind Params. Tipos: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob
//No caso são 3 Strings, então o primeiro parâmetro do bind_param receberá 'sss';
//Caso tivesse algum inteiro por exemplo, poderia ser 'ssis'... e assim por diante.
//Cuidado para não trocar a ordem que você forneceu("INSERT INTO campeoes (champ_nome, champ_descricao, champ_avatar)..."); no caso a ordem é: champ_nome, champ_descricao, champ_avatar.

$adiciona_champ->bind_param('sss', $champ_nome, $champ_desc, $champ_avatar);
$adiciona_champ->execute();


//Continuação
```

---

Outra solução pode ser a função `filter_input` (mais usado para validação e filtrar informações de fontes inseguras), que provê a captura de parâmetros externos podendo aplicar filtros específicos.

**Explicação da documentação:**

> filter_input — Gets a specific external variable by name and
>   optionally filters it

Sintaxe: `filter_input(tipo, variável, filtro(opcional:vide documentação));`
Para filtrar caracteres especiais você pode passar o filtro: `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS`.

**Seu código aplicando o filter_input;**

```
//Filtrar caracteres especiais
$champ_nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome-champ', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
//Filtrar caracteres especiais
$champ_desc = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'desc-champ', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

O complemento ideal para a continuação do código seria a utilização de Prepared Statement e não a concatenação direta na String SQL.

**Referências/Complementos:**

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)
  [Tipos de Filtro](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php)
 [PHP Prepared Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Caso precise de mais alguma coisa, ou gostaria que adicionasse mais informações a resposta, por favor avise.